# If everything has taken on forms from eternal past in various rebirths, why are we not already born with self realization of moksha?

Tags: moksha, atma, jiva

I have read that the soul is eternally present. Since the eternal past it has undergone an infinite amount of rebirths without beginning. Why is the realization of moksha needed at that specific point temporally? If it took an infinite amount of time to realize moksha, shouldn't it take an infinite amount of time to realize it further?

Comment: Because you were not a yogi(who practiced karm yog, gyan yog or bhakti yog and failed ) in previous life. Also mind is atatached to body. So, it's changed. But soul remains same

Comment: Your question is dependent on continuity that must exist for the soul. Remember, continuity exists because of the existence of time only. Time is a product of Maya and will never lead you to the true origin. It's like you see a dream and you are aware that you are in a different world and you want to trace back the origin of the world inside the dream to know why Moksha is needed at a specific point of the time. But Advaita says, that even time is a product of ignorance or Maya and this traceback won't lead you to an answer. Origin of dream world is only clear when you wake up, not traceback!

Answer (score 1):

आब्रह्मभुवनाल्लोका: पुनरावर्तिनोऽर्जुन |
मामुपेत्य तु कौन्तेय पुनर्जन्म न विद्यते ||

When humans are born first time on Earth they are born with little sins but with more realisation of God (incarnating or bringing God's powers on Earth). But Earth is a place that is above to all living forms and living forms are subjected to weaknesses by Demon spirits.

"If everything has taken on forms from eternal past in various rebirths?

Not everything taken to rebirths, but living beings(humans) who feed much on Karmic foods for survival by destroying souls of them take rebirths. Other souls are disposed off. Example an ant gets disposed off its soul though it is a form of living being. But human souls dont get disposed off due to demoniac effects.
MOKSHA PATH
Moksha path is to avoid rebirths. Primitive influenced invaded forms are not Eternal forms.

Chathur VARNA are majority first time Divinely born. But, nowadays we have many derived castes from the Varna because over ages, humans found themselves hard ethically to survive on Earth in bad influences by Demon spirits thus failing to protect Divine born. Due to same reason, feeding on other lives increased leaning towards Demonism.

To avoid rebirths, there had been ETERNAL SECRETS revealed to humans in indirect ways as to attain MOKSHA.

The above ways are UNIVERSAL to all humans on Earth because humans "only take pride on whatever actions one may perform" and the pride is not with other primitive Divine souls that get disposed off (Ants, Honey bees, Swans, Cows) etc.

Answer (score 0):

**So why is the realization of moksha needed at that specific point temporally ? If it took an infinite amount of time to realize moksha, shouldnt it take an infinite amount of time to realize it further?**

I will give an answer from the Advaita Vedanta point of view. It is ignorance (Avidya Maya) which veils the Reality.

**Avidya Maya**

> Advaita Vedanta says that ignorance of Brahman has created this world.
> Ignorance, which is the opposite of knowledge (jnana-virodhi), is not
> something negative. It has a positive character (bhavarupa).
>
> It has two powers: (1) the veiling power (avarana-shakti) and (2) the
> power of projection (vikshepa-shakti). **Ignorance has the power to
> cover or veil the Reality, which is Brahman,** and also the power to
> project this world on the veiled or covered Reality.
>
> The world is the product of mula-avidya. The individual ego, which is
> part of this world, is also the product of mula-avidya. Consciousness
> associated with this ego is called the Atman or the Jivatman. Between
> the Jivatman and Brahman (Paramatman) there is a thin veil of
> ignorance. It is like a cloud that does not allow an individual to see
> the sun. In this analogy the Brahman is the sun and the patch of cloud
> is the ignorance of the individual. When this individual’s ignorance
> is dispelled by the knowledge of Brahman, he or she will have the
> experience of Brahman.

**Journey from Many to one *essentials of Advaita Vedanta*** by Swami Bhaskarananda

We are really Brahman but due to the veil we are convinced that we are human. The veil might last a long time. However, when this veil is lifted we realize our mistake and identify with the Atman. Even if the veil was there for infinite time it can lift in a moment. An analogy would be fog covering the Sun. The day will be misty and foggy when the fog is present. When, however, the fog lifts the day becomes sunny in an instant. So just because ignorance has been there for infinite time does not imply that we will have to wait for infinite time to gain knowledge of the Atman.

Answer (score -1):

Moksha is not an action, it's simply a realization. The moment that realization occurs in its true form (when the Ahamkaara completely identifies itself as the Sat-Chit-Ananda Brahma) is the moment when moksha (Jivanmukti) occurs.

It's not an action or change, but rather a realization, that YOU (Atma) were always free, limitless, voiceless, eyeless, formless etcetc, the moment it occurs, moksha is achieved.

> Why is the realization of moksha needed at that specific point temporally?

Think of it like this. I'll use the famous snake-rope metaphor. Suppose you saw a snake, then you got scared and started palpitating and doing all sorts of things (like shouting), but then, you realized that it's not a snake, but just a rope. Then, everything goes back to normal.

Similarly, you are already free, the Ahamkaara (the feeling of I) incorrectly identifies itself with the memories it sees, with the sights it sees, with the emotions it feels, with the people it knows, with the skin color of the body it sees etc. Then, the Ahamkaara realizes that all those things are not 'I' at that moment, Moksha occurs.

Now, why is Moksha occurring at a MOMENT in time rather than infinitely, if you were bound infinitely, and not for a moment? Well, it's simply because you were never bound, there was never a snake.

Suppose you're a beggar who's living like a beggar for 30 years. Then, you start working and eventually become a billionare in 30 years. Is that how Moksha works? **NO.**

Moksha rather works in this way: Suppose you're a young 20 something girl, who's madly searching for her lost great golden necklace full of sapphires. Then, you realize that it was on your neck the whole time. That's what moksha is like. It's NOT a transformation or 'becoming' something else, it's a realization that doesn't change anything about reality. Even if you were searching for that necklace for 10 hours, you need only one second (or rather, one instant) to realize it's on your neck.

You don't need to work to get moksha (you work to become eligible for moksha), moksha occurs instantly as it's a realization. You realizing where the necklace is can ONLY occur at one point in time, right? Does a realization ever take years or even seconds? Not at all. Every time, it's an instantaneous moment. It's not an action or transformation, where there is step 1, step 2 etc till the final moment of the result.

This opens up question about the fate of the Ahamkaara's future, which is slightly shady to go into. Since, the Ahamkaara realizes it's the Aatma, but, what if it again thinks it's not the Atma??? But, we will assume Shastra Pramana is true and, the Shastra says that the Ahamkaara ceases to be after death if one dies in a state of Jivanmukti.

> If it took an infinite amount of time to realize moksha, shouldn't it take an infinite amount of time to realize it further?

It didn't take an infinite amount of time to realize Moksha. It took an infinite amount of time till the point you were ready to realize Moksha. Moksha occurred in an instantly small period of time, or rather, Moksha never occurred, since there's no freedom or bondage. Only the realization occured (which happened instantly).

Let me provide another crude metaphor. Suppose, you're a body builder. You trained for 10 years, then entered a competition, then you won. You won at ONE moment in time, the moment your name was announced. You trained for 10 years. See how those two things are different? Moksha occurs instantly, the Saadhnaa to make you eligible for Moksha (Dhyaana/Bhakti/Shanti etc) took 10 years (or infinite amount of itme, rather).

Or another metaphor, I thought up just now. Suppose you go to a boarding school, and spend 5 years there. Then you leave. Should it take 5 years for you to leave? Of course not, right? Just that, in this case, replace 5 years with inifinte amount of time. You've been in the school of life for infinity, and at any single second, you can decide to leave. And, there's a secondary change, that once you leave, you cannot enter back, no matter what.

The form to leave the school (Upanayana and ShadKarma of Brahmana), saying good bye to your friends (removing detachment), walking to the exit (Vedaacharana, Yama, Niyama), taking permission from the teacher and principle (serving guru and doing bhakti of Ishvara) and so on, may take a few hours(one life in comparison to infinity isn't even one hour). But, the occurrence of you leaving the school only occurs at one singular infinitely small moment. Because, there's only two states, moksha, or non moksha. And the change in states, is instant. There's no instant where you're in both.